# How to determine if a number is a binary or not?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, binary

`my_l1:str = "0101011"`

I execute this code:

```
for character in my_l1:
    if character != '0' and character != '1':
       print (f"{my_l1} is not a binary number")
    else:
       print(f"{my_l1} is a binary number")
```

and I get this output:

```
0101011 is a binary number
0101011 is a binary number
0101011 is a binary number
0101011 is a binary number
0101011 is a binary number
0101011 is a binary number
0101011 is a binary number
```

How do I get just a single line output which goes like this?

```
0101011 is a binary number.
```

Comment: Just an idea for an alternative version. Do `int(my_l1, 2)` and catch a possible `ValueError`.

Comment: BTW, the output doesn't match your code. You will get this output if the last line were indented to be part of the `for` loop.

Comment: im sorry , yea i didnt noticed that , i have edited the code

Answer (score 1):

You can add `break` and `for..else`. `break` will end the loop.

```
my_l1:str = "0101011"

for character in my_l1:
    if character != '0' and character != '1':
       print (f"{my_l1} is not a binary number")
       break
else:
    print (f"{my_l1} is a binary number")
```

Prints:

```
  0101011 is a binary number.
```

---

You can rewrite the code with `all()`:

```
my_l1:str = "0101011"

if all(ch=='0' or ch=='1' for ch in my_l1):
    print (f"{my_l1} is a binary number")
else:
    print (f"{my_l1} is not a binary number")
```

Comment: this one works for me , quick question though, is it necessary to add break to both if and else statements?

Comment: @incognitomodus `break` is only necessary put in `if` statement that is inside for-loop. Notice: the `else:` is indented under `for`, not under `if`

Comment: incognitomodus: Using the `all()` method would be the shortest and fastest way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def isBinary(num: str):
    for i in num:
        if i not in ["0","1"]:
            return False
    return True
```

```
if isBinary("000101") == True:
    print("000101 is binary")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 my_l1:str = "0101011"
 isBinary=True ## We Assume it's True (i.e, the number is a binary) until we prove to 
               ## the contrary, so this boolean variable is used to check (if binary 
               ## or not)
 for character in my_l1:
        if character != '0' and character != '1':
                  sBinary=False ## once we find a number in the list my_l1 different 
                                ## than "0" and "1"  it is not necessary to continue 
                                ## looping through the list, because the number is not 
                                ## a binary anymore, so we break in order to consume 
                                ## time
                  break
 
  if isBinary: ## i.e, if isBinary==True then do :
          print (f"{my_l1} is a binary number")
  else:
          print(f"{my_l1} is not a binary number")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @KimTang, I appreciate it.